# Implementing IDataErrorInfo interface

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I have some problems in using this interface. In my class "Researcher", which is a realization of IDataErrorInfo, I write such thing:

```
[Serializable]
public class Researcher : Person, IDeepCopy, IEnumerable, IComparable, IComparer, IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get 
        { 
            return date; 
        }
        set
        {
            date = value;           
        }
    } 
    //...

    public string Error { get { return "Error Text"; } }

    public string this[string property]
    {
        get
        {
            string msg = null;
            if ((this.Date.Year < 1930 && this.Date.Year > 1990) && (this.projjects.Count < 0))
                msg = "Not Correct Date";

            return msg;

        }
    }
    //...
}
```

And in my XAML code:

```
<TextBox Name="birthday"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="{Binding Date,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" /> `
```

But this doesn't check anything and I can still enter any Date I want into the TextBox. What is the problem?

Comment: Could it be that (this.Date.Year < 1930 && this.Date.Year > 1990) is always false? Year can't be both less than 1930 and greater than 1990... I think you probably want the && (and) to be a || (or)?

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. But if the problem is that the text in the textbox is not updated, try to call `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Date");` Else, the UI will never know that the variable has changed.

Comment: i agree with @J.H. looking like you meant ||| not &&, however you should be using the property parameter to select the validation rules and validate each property indevidually

Comment: It also seems unlikely that `this.projjects.Count < 0` could be true.

Comment: Does your single class really implement 6 unrelated interfaces?

Comment: I didn't write them here because here they are not actual

Comment: @fghjkl4083 I think what they mean is that 6 is a rather large number, on average 2 or 3 is all you'd normally need, you should double check if you really need that many, however it is possible you do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would suggest changing it to something similar to this

```
public string Error { get { return string.Empty; } }
public string this[string property]
{
    get
    {
        var msg = new StringBuilder();
        switch(property)
        {
            case "Date":
                if(Date <1930) msg.AppendLine("Date must be greater than 1930");
                if(Date >1990) msg.AppendLine("Date must be less than 1990");
                break;
            case "projjects":
                if(projjects.Count <= 0) msg.AppendLine("projjects must contain atleast 1 item");
                break;
        }

        return msg.ToString();
    }
}`
```

as this allows you to return meaningful errors and checks each property separately

also you need to trigger the property changed event
so changing to

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return date; }
    set
    {
        date = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedArg("Date"); 
    }
}
```

would also be needed